¿porqué el textarea no se cuadra igual que los demás inputs aunque le estoy dando las mismas propiedades?
Mi problema es que le estoy dando las mismas propiedades a los input y al texarea pero el textarea no se alinea igual, se desborda ¿Por qué no queda con las mismas proporciones?
Se ve así:

Este es el código html:
<div class="div_1">
    <form>
        <h2>formulario de contacto</h2>
        <div class="caja">
            <input  type="text" placeholder="Nombre Completo" >
        </div>
        <div class="caja">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div>
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

y en css lo tengo así:


.div_1 {
  background: #222;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 400px;
  border: 10px solid #000;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 22px;
}

form {
  margin: 80px;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px #fff3;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.caja {
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

input,textarea {
  min-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #0003;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #999;
}



cual podría ser el factor que ocasiona ese descuadre en el textarea, estoy intentando enviar el codigo completo necesario para que me puedan ayudar pero acá la pagina me pide que escriba mas, porque no me deja enviarlo me sale error entonces por eso estoy escribiendo esto a ver si al agregarle este texto me deja enviarlo

Agrega el HTML también de los inputs y el text area, así como el css de los inputs, para que podamos ver que le ocurre. Es decir, haz un [example] correcto, por favor, sino vamos bastante a ciegas.

Pues a simple vista parece que funciona bien (https://jsfiddle.net/b65r3joc/), pero claro, no vemos lo que es la clase caja y ahí debe estar el problema.  Pon tambien el css de caja.

Te lo he puesto en un snippet para que lo veas aquí mismo si lo ejecutas.

Te faltó añadirle la clase 'caja' al div padre del textarea, te quedaría algo así:


.div_1 {
  background: #222;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 400px;
  border: 10px solid #000;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 22px;
}

form {
  margin: 80px;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px #fff3;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.caja {
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

input,textarea {
  min-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #0003;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #999;
}
<div class="div_1">
    <form>
        <h2>formulario de contacto</h2>
        <div class="caja">
            <input  type="text" placeholder="Nombre Completo" >
        </div>
        <div class="caja">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="caja"> <!-- clase caja añadida -->
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>



